# Delay writing to txt file a batch file's output

Tags: java, batch-file

I have some java code that runs a batch file on jButton click.

```
Batch file content: @dsquery computer -name *%1
```

This batch file is supposed to search the active directory for the full computer name when I enter a partial part of the computer name into a jtextfield. When I click the jButton to submit, it works fine. I get the full computer name in cmd prompt, but the txt file outputs every computer it went through to find the correct computer. I need the txt file to only output the computer name I'm searching for. Is there a way to delay writing to txt file until the name is found and then write to the text file? Or perhaps maybe another way? [image]

Comment: Without seeing the code that outputs to the text file, I can't say for certain, but when you find the computer name you're looking for, you could store it to a variable and then send that variable to the text file after the entire search is complete.

Comment: Do you mean storing it to a cmd prompt variable or java variable?

Comment: Again, I haven't seen your code, but I was imagining a Java variable (admittedly, I'm only seeing this question because of the batch-file tag; I haven't touched Java in about five years).

Comment: Why do you need the delay ? Do you monitor the file for existance ? If yes: dsquery > first, and in the next line copy first monitorme

Comment: I want the output of the text file to only show the computer that was found. If you look at the cmd prompt pic you will see the correct computer name, but the text file I'm guessing is outputting every single computer name it had to go through in order to find the correct one. I want notepad to only show the correct computer name. So the txt file should only have one line outputted to it just like command prompt is doing. Also I'm a little confused by what you mean Marged? Do you mean to write  @dsquery computer -name *%1 > first  Next Line: first monitorme? Is that what I need to write?

Comment: I just got it to work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

its been 8 years, but..
to delay the result writing to a batch file you should add
timeout then the delay in seconds
for example timeout 5 will delay the result for 5 seconds.
Have a good day!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).